# select unique list from list<string> using linq and substring c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
List<string> fileListServiceLine;
```

below are the values in the list;

```
A073662937EMC900200202EST PT-OFF/OPD VISIT          0016224DIAGNOSTIC LAB TEST
A098281448EMC900700103EST PT-OFF/OPD VISIT          0016111SELFCARE TRAINING
```

I have an identifier

```
string identifier = EMC9002002;
```

I get this identifier value from config file.

In my practical case scenario I get more than 2 values in the list string mentioned above.

I am trying to filter the list fileListServiceLine and get only those values which match identifier.
identifier will be present in one of the items in the fileListServiceLine list and only one list item will be a matching case.

I am trying the below code it is not giving the exact result.

```
var servLineRecords = fileListServiceLine.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(location.ServiceLineIdentifierStart - 1, location.ServiceLineIdentifierLength) == identifier );
```

location.ServiceLineIdentifierStart and location.ServiceLineIdentifierLength 
I will get above values from config file to locate the exact position of identifer matching value.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: you can use `fileListServiceLine.Where(s=>s.Contains(identifier))`

Comment: Do you actually want to ``group`` your data? I understood it that you only want to ``filter``, so to do that you should use ``.Where`` instead of ``.GroupBy`` ?!?

Comment: what type is `location` ? and what is the value of  `ServiceLineIdentifierStart` and `ServiceLineIdentifierLength`?

Answer (score 3):

Use this linq statement:

```
var servLineRecords = fileListServiceLine.Where(s => s.ToLower().Contains(identifier.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Contains()` method instead like below. Since you know there will be only one value matching the identifier you can use `First()` and get the first item

```
fileListServiceLine.Where(s => s.Contains(identifier)).First();
```

In case, you want to do a case insensitive search then use `IndexOf()` method instead like

```
fileListServiceLine.SingleOrDefault(s => s.IndexOf(identifier, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: You don't need to call `Where` and `First`.  You can just call `First` and pass the filter expression to it. Also, the question says that only one match will exist, so it's more appropriate to call `Single` than `First`. The question doesn't mention whether there will always be a match but, if there may not be, then `SingleOrDefault` would be the correct option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx). e.g,

```
fileListServiceLine.Single(s => s.Contains(identifier));
```

`Single` will throw an exception if there isn't exactly one match, whereas `SingleOrDefault` will instead return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Contains()` combined with some lower-casing using `ToLower()` on both of the strings to find the matching element. `FirstOrDefault()` returns default value if no element is found.

```
var record = fileListServiceLine.Where(s => s.ToLower().Contains(identifier.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();
```